# Get a specific column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
private readonly FullStackDBContext _fullStackDbContext;
        public ProductsController(FullStackDBContext fullStackDbContext)
        {
            _fullStackDbContext = fullStackDbContext;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task <IActionResult> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var products= await _fullStackDbContext.Products.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(products);
        }
```

Hi, I have been trying to get a specific column from my database. I am new to entity framework core and the code above is written from a youtube video. I am looking for a way to get a specific column value since the code above returns all values. Is there a way to execute a custom query? Because I think the code given above is not written using any query. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "I am looking for a way to get a specific column value since the code above returns all values. "Can you get all values now?

Comment: @QingGuo yes I can get all the values using the code **var products= await _fullStackDbContext.Products.ToListAsync();** But the code gives the whole table while I only want a column of the table

Comment: "The page in swagger cannot reload and give Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () error "  Where did you meet this error? Have you set the breakpoint at" var products= await _fullStackDbContext.Products.Select(x=> x.Id).ToListAsync();" to see the value of the products?

Comment: The error was found when I run the program. The error appears in the console in the browser. When I use the code above, swagger will show the output normally. In case I'm not explaining well, swagger is a thing like a postman as the video tutorial said and I run this code in visual studio code

Comment: `.Select(x=> x.ColumnName)` should contain your specific column name, which is one of  your model property.

Comment: Could you share the code you used? And could you show us the relationship of the  model and the  specific column ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` on your table name. like below

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task <IActionResult> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var products= await _fullStackDbContext.Products.Select(x=> x.ColumnName).ToListAsync();

        return Ok(products);
    }
```

You can also rename column if you want like below

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task <IActionResult> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var products= await _fullStackDbContext.Products.Select(x=> new {
        NewNmae= x.ColumnName
        }).ToListAsync();

        return Ok(products);
    }
```

Comment: It is not working. The page in swagger cannot reload and give **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()** error